# What is the sample size when we take repeated measures?

Tags: repeated-measures, sample-size, definition

Say we're running an experiment and we have 10 volunteers. From each of these 10 volunteers we take 3 measurements. So we end up with a dataset that has thirty rows.

Say we're writing up the results. Should we report that n = 30 or n = 10?

Comment: What are these 3 measurements ? Are they 3 (imprecise) measures of the exact same quantity or measures of a variable that evolves through time at 3 different dates ?

Comment: I'm not sure…didn't think about that (my example is hypothetical). Is it important?

Comment: If the variable evolves through time, then what you have is a panel (sample size 10), with measures taken at 3 different dates. If they are measures of the same concept, it means that you have to take into account a variance term for each estimation (and then it'd be arguable that sample size is 30).